# CIFS with WD NAS

Tags: linux, samba, cifs, nas

I use a My Cloud Home Duo from WD. Rather than using the web interface I would like to use CIFS under Linux.

I tried the following commands based [on](https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detailweb/a_id/30614/track/AvODPwpRDv8Q%7EQZvGgEe%7EyJjeDEq_C75Mv9D%7Ezj%7EPP_K):

1. sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.3/Public ~/mycloud -o username=email,password=pass
2. sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.3/Public ~/mycloud2 -o username=guest,password=guest

Unfortunately, in both cases, the mounted directory is empty despite uploading many files via the web interface. What did I do wrong?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Ideas for troubleshooting: Use smbclient to access the share. Upload something after mounting or smbclient connection and check if the uploaded file is visible via the GUI.

Comment: After mounting I got ```$ touch ~/mycloud/test
touch: cannot touch '/home/pi/mycloud/test': Permission denied```. What did I miss?

Comment: The error message indicates that the CIFS user doesn't have the right permissions to create a file there. Which makes me suspect that it doesn't have the right permissions to read files either.

Comment: Try adding to the `-o` options `uid=1000` where 1000 is your Unix id you are running touch from. (Some cifs accept the name too). If that fails, also add `forceuid`. See `man mount.cifs`.

Comment: I used `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.3/Public ~/mycloud2 -o username=email,password=pass,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),forceuid,forcegid` and was able to write a file, but I still can't see any other files which I uploaded via the web GUI.

Comment: I don't know anything about WD Mycloud, but for a typical NAS using CIFS you would replace the share name `Public` by the name of your private share, which *might* be the same as what you put in `username=`. Usually, the case (uppercase/lowercase) is ignored. For info, the username `guest` is a special reserved name that is used for "public" access with the password ignored. It might work with the `Public` share, but it is unlikely to work for a private share.